# Google Play Console, Cannot Install Application Error

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have published an app on a closed test track on google play console.

[image]

When I use this test link here.

[image]

It shows up in the store, and I can press install. It finishes the download. Then the following error happens. Have tested on several android devices.

[image]

The testing devices account is the same as the email in the testers list. The application works fine on an emulated device in android studio.

Can anyone think what could be the error? The pre-launch report also shows that it works on several devices.

Comment: Do you have the debug version installed? If so, uninstall it as the signing certificates will be conflicting.

Comment: HI @user14678216. Thanks for the suggestion. But no I do not have the debug version installed. Google Play have responded mentioning that only one track can be active at a time. So I had to close my internal test track. After doing this, and clearing the cache and data the same issue persists.